# Setting geom_boxplot line tickness based on significant difference

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I'm trying to highlight the significant difference of specific groups compared to a control by making their respective boxplots and labels bold. However, I have no idea how I should start with this. Right now I have something like this:

```
cat <- c(replicate(50, "a"), replicate(50, "b"), replicate(50, "c"))
foo <- rnorm(150)
bar <- c(rnorm(100, 2), rnorm(50, 4))
foobar <- c(rnorm(50, 5), rnorm(100,2))
df <- data.frame("category" = cat, "foo" = foo, "bar" = bar, "foobar" = foobar) %>% gather(key = "key", value = "value", 2:4)

ggplot(df, aes(x=category, y=value)) + 
  geom_boxplot() +
  facet_grid(key ~ .)
```

Which produces following image:

[image]

Lets say that for category "b" and "c" the measurement of "foobar" is significantly different compared to "a", and for category "c" the measurement of "c" compared to "a" as well. Is there a way to highlight these boxplots (e.g. making them bold)?

Thank you

Comment: You could add a column to df called `signif` containing a factor variable that labels all the rows containing a significant category as "significant" and the rest "non-significant". Then in your ggplot do `aes(x=category, y=yvalue, size=signif)`. To change the line thickness to your tastes use `scale_size_discrete`

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way I can think of to highlight specific boxplots based on standard deviation of the set.  As long as you follow the programming logic here, you should be able to adapt to other labeling methods.

The general approach is to process your dataset to include categorical data as extra columns, then use those columns you created to apply an aesthetic to the boxplot.

```
# create a column for standard deviation for individual categories within the groups
df.avg <- df %>% group_by(key,category) %>% summarize(sd.val=sd(value))

# merge both datasets to "add" the summary data in long/tidy format
df.merge <- merge(df, df.avg)

# the plot
ggplot(df.merge, aes(x=category, y=value)) + 
    geom_boxplot(aes(fill=sd.val), alpha=0.8) +
    facet_grid(key ~ .) +
    scale_fill_gradient(name='Std Dev', high='red', low='green')
```

[image]

If you only want to label a "threshold" of standard deviation (e.g. only sd values that are higher than 1.1 in red), this could work:

```
ggplot(df.merge, aes(x=category, y=value)) + 
    geom_boxplot(aes(fill=eval(sd.val>1.1)), alpha=0.8) +
    facet_grid(key ~ .) +
    scale_fill_manual(name=NULL, values=list('TRUE'='red', 'FALSE'='white'),
        labels=list('TRUE'='High SD', 'FALSE'='Low SD'))
```

[image]

Comment: This solution together with Allan Cameron's suggestion got exactly what I wanted, thanks!